# How can I exit MVS CICS?

Tags: terminal

I logged into MVS CICS to view an application, which I found I do not have ACF2 rights to.  How can I exit CICS?

I've tried.

- `exit`
- `quit`
- <kbd>F3</kbd>

All of which present me with the error message:

```
MVSCICS Transaction 'QUIT' is not recognized.
Check that the transaction name is correct.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transaction is `logoff`. On some older machines it's `cssf logoff`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using an antiquated system like this and this didn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: For me it was just `cssf`

Comment: [CESF (Signoff) and CSSF (Signoff)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAL2T_8.2.0/com.ibm.cics.tx.doc/reference/r_cesf_cssf.html)